# Safari doesn't load one image

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

I have some trouble about displaying image. There is no problem with the google chrome or ie but when I open the page with safari my toggle(jquery) image is not displaying. Any idea why is this happening?

**this is the chrome**

[image]

**and this one is safari**

[image]

And I already check `develop->disable image` and `preferences->enable java script`. looks like no problem with that.

*Css*

```
#x-icon img {
    content:"";
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
    border-top: 5px solid orange;
    border-right: 5px solid orange;
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: -45%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: 85%;
    margin-top: -70px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: maybe it is problem in css please show us code

Comment: I added css code for the icon/button

Comment: I solved the problem. It's because of this: `content:"";` but thank you anyway

Comment: OMG i just come to write you to delete it... LOL

Comment: The `content` property is used with the `::before` and `::after `pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp